# Rack::Session::Pool with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra webapp I've built using `enable :sessions` where I access my session data with `session[:mything]`.

I now want to store data on the server side (ie. with database based sessions) and I can't figure out how to use `Rack::Session::Pool`, which appears to be the thing I need to use.

How do I go about converting my webapp for use with Pool?

I know I need to add the line

```
use Rack::Session::Pool
```

what comes next? — thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Here's an example using cookie-based sessions:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

enable :sessions

get '/' do
  session.merge!(params)
  session.inspect
end
```

Visit `/?hi=there` then visit `/` and you'll still see `{'hi'=>'there'}`, as it's been stored in a cookie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply replace the line `enable :sessions` with `use Rack::Session::Pool`.
All `enable :session` does is adding `Rack::Session::Cookie` to the stack (which you want to avoid). The `session` helper will still work.

Comment: Rack::Session::Cookie provides simple cookie based session management.

Comment: @Liber OP needs a different kind of session, not the one that `Rack::Session::Cookie` provide, hence Konstantin Hasse's answer.